# REST Service - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: services, 8

I has been trying to set up a drupal *REST Server* in my computer (a clean drupal 6  installation). Unfortunately, I could not configure it. When I send a *POST message* (WITHOUT parameters);

`ht.p://localhst/drupal/?q=note/note/retrieve` or  `ht.p://localhst/drupal/?q=note/user/login`, it replies *500 Internal Server Error*.

I used this example (I copied and pasted the example to sites/all/modules)  https://drupal.org/node/783460.

It is a drupal 6.28 in a Debian with Apache2. It has not configured clean URLs!

I am using the module [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) (6.x-3.4-rc1) and [Rest Server](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_server) (6.x-2.0-beta3).

I checked the `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

> [Sun Jun 23 17:11:24.136866 2013] [:error] [pid 2957] [client ::1:48424] PHP
>
> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function services_resource_uri_formatter() in /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/rest_server/includes/RESTServer.inc on line 15

I have another doubt, how is it possible to test these services easily? These error messages for me are  not intuitive. I was using drush with watchdog but
I didn't give more information.

Regards.

Comment: From your post. Your endpoint of services is note, right? So if you config the services correctly and use the REST SERVER, when you access the link: ht.p://localhst/drupal/?q=note. You'll get the message for your installation successful or not. So what did you get when access that link?

Comment: I tested ht.p://localhst/drupal/?q=note and I received another "500 Internal Server Error" (same errors...)

Comment: Did you create the endpoint for services at http://localhst/drupal/?q=admin/build/services? Please do two steps to test your endpoint. 1. Add new endpoint correctly. 2. Use [Poster firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/) to call the system connect service at : http://localhst/drupal/?q=yourendpoint/system/connect. If it returns a xml message with sessid, uid, hostname. It means you did config for endpoint correctly and you can move forward to do something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was when I used the drush tool. It downloaded and installed the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module, and the [Rest Server](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_server) module (another no necessary module).

This error was describing this conflict between modules;

> [Sun Jun 23 17:11:24.136866 2013] [:error] [pid 2957] [client::1:48424] PHP
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
> services_resource_uri_formatter() in
> /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/rest_server/includes/RESTServer.inc
> on line 15

I disabled the [Rest Server](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_server) and restarted the *HTTP server*.